# Oracle pl/sql with variables: Creating Sequence with current date and host address

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here's a simple question about how to create a sequence with variables.
I wanna create a sequence using a combination of system time as it's start value. How should I do that.

Here's what I wrote:

```
DECLARE
  SQS number :=(sysdate - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (864000);
  sql_stmt varchar2(200);
BEGIN
  sql_stmt := 'create SEQUENCE XXXX_id_seq MINVALUE  100000 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH :1 CACHE 500 NOORDER CYCLE';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using SQS;
END;
```

but it says invalid num.
I know it's a noobie question. but I really need help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind variables in DDL statements (I ain't got doc or a good reason why, but quite a few references mentioning the fact), you've got to concatenate all in one.

```
DECLARE
  SQS number :=(sysdate - to_date('01-JANV.-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (864000);
  sql_stmt varchar2(200);
BEGIN
  sql_stmt := 'create SEQUENCE XXXX_id_seq MINVALUE  100000 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '||SQS||' CACHE 500 NOORDER CYCLE';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt ;
END;
```

Comment: Bind variables are used as placeholders in execution plans, to avoid the need to reparse them.  We shouldn't be running DDL statements often enough for reparsing to be an issue, and even if we do, DDL is usually an expensive operation anyway and the parsing pahse is likely to be a small part of it.

Comment: @APC thanx for explanation. I just think that the error message should be "smarter" in this case !

Comment: I agree that some Oracle errors have messages which are almost wilfully incomprehensible.  It's part of the charm ;)